# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Javascript issues

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I've updated my Visual Studio 2015 to update 3 today.
Since I did this I've had 3 different issues/bugs which happen randomly;

- 1 javascript file was opened in 2 different tabs in the same main VS window.
- Image the following line:

  > var test = "test";

Highlighting the variable 'test' would highlight 'var test' and even 2 empty tabs in front it ...

- No intellisense during debugging on no specific third party stuff ... just basic declared variables.

Anyone got an idea how I can fix this?

Regards,
Yannick